# Can't reproduce a "bug" in git without a specific file

Tags: git, debugging

I think I found a bug of git, but I can't reproduce it without a specific file, unfortunately that file is copyrighted and I can't post it on the internet.

I'll describe the process and wish someone can give a clue of how to reproduce this with another file.

my file's name is `epmdstyp.h` I ran `git difftool -d` and then git generated two temp folders, I copied out the original version of this file and the latest version, their contents are almost identical, just some slight changes in the comments. Btw, these two file's size and time stamp are exactly the same.

then I ran commands in the screenshot.

[image]

Git failed to detect the content changes...

I am 100% sure the two files are **NOT** the same. But I can't reproduce the bug with any other files, so I can't report it to git's buglist. Any thoughts?

Comment: 1. Can you reproduce the bug on Linux with native git?
2. If you explicitly touch the new file after copying it, does msysgit detect the change when you do git diff?

Comment: I don't have linux beside me right now, I can test on Mac when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a difficult one.

You could try to narrow down the problem (a sort of [Delta Debugging](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/dd/)).

1. Write a script that reproduces the bug automatically (and run it to test it works).
2. Start making small modifications to the file `epmdstyp.h`. Try taking out half the file - can you still reproduce the bug? What if you only change a single character?
3. Refine further based on the information you gained.

Maybe you find that the bug occurs if the file has a certain number of lines, or bytes. Or maybe it's triggered by a specific line.

Ideally, you can reproduce the problem with a file without confidential information, then you can post to the mailing list. If you cannot, you'll have to investigate further. Then you can ask another question here :-).

Comment: If I just save the file and change it's timestamp, git will behave normally. I don't need to make changes to the file's content to break this bug's reproduce process.

Comment: @shengy: Ok, important point. Still, try what I suggested. Once you can reproduce the problem with a script, try the script with a slightly changed file. Can you still reproduce it?